# Restrictions on tying grounds together?

Tags: grounding

I'm replacing the hard line to the garbage disposal. Instead of the hard line i'm installing an outlet. The box where the garbage disposal switch is located has two circuits in it. One is for the disposal and the other is for an outlet.

The wiring in my house is soldered. With the old wiring all the grounds were brought together to a single spot, soldered together and a lead came out to ground the GFCI outlet. Now that i'm replacing the line and the switch (which now also has a grounding point, the old one did not) i need to connect. If I can help it I would rather not disturb the soldering.

I'm thinking, leave a lead to the soldered bundle, then tie all the new grounds to the lead. Would this be up to code or do I need only a single ground bundle?

PS I live in Ohio USA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solder only connections are a code violation. A metal crimp on the soldered connection with your new wire would be the best way to tie the grounds together.
[crimp](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-14-8-AWG-Copper-Crimp-Sleeves-50-Pack-CPGI-CCS-14-8-C-50/205878599).